# Yii2 kartik select2 widget showing values too issue

Tags: php, yii2, kartik-v

I have created a yii2 kartik select2 widget to select multiple car models like below

```
<?= Select2::widget([
        'name' => 'drp-make',
        'data' => Car::getCarMakesEnglish(),
        'value' => explode(",",$model->drp_make),
        'options' => [
          'id'=>'drp-make',
          'placeholder' => 'All Makes',
          'multiple' => true
        ]
      ]); ?>
```

And the function to get data for the select2 like

```
 public static function getCarMakesEnglish(){
            $out=array();
        $makes=CarMakes::find()->select(['id','make_eng'])->all();
        foreach ($makes as $make) {
            array_push($out,array($make['id'] => $make['make_eng']));
        }
        return $out;
    }
```

Its working perfect.But a issue is there.please see the below picture

[image]

Its showing values too not only the names.I want to show only the make names.How to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are pushing an array to every index of the `$out`

```
array_push($out,array($make['id'] => $make['make_eng']))
```

you should use [`yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/helper-array) instead that do this for you. Change your function `getCarMakesEnglish()` to the following

```
public static function getCarMakesEnglish()
{
    $makes = CarMakes::find()->select(['id', 'make_eng'])->all();
    return \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map($makes,'id','make_eng');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @MuhammadOmerAslam answer, you can avoid `ArrayHelper::map()` for simple scenario by using [column()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-query#column()-detail)

```
public static function getCarMakesEnglish()
{
    return CarMakes::find()->select('make_eng')->indexBy('id')->column();
}
```